# Gson and generic not work

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a class

```
public class ContactsData<T> {

    @SerializedName(value = "data")
    public ArrayList<T> data;

    public ContactsData<T> fromJson(String json) {
        return BBAPI.getGson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ContactsData<T>>() {
        }.getType());
    }

}
```

then i try deserialize class from json with function fromJson i got Object ContactsData but in array data not objects of type T, but LinkedTreeMap

How to do correct?

I want use on class not subclasses, because i have responses from server with one format

```
{"data":[array of different types]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register a custom type adapter for each T type.

For example:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(MyCustomClass.class, new MyCustomClassInstanceCreator()).create();
```

Where:

```
class MyCustomClassInstanceCreator implements JsonDeserializer<MyCustomClass>
{
  @Override
  public MyCustomClass deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException
  {
    MyCustomClass instance = ...create instance from parameters
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample

```
public <T> T readGsonObject(HttpEntity httpEntity, Class<T> tClass) throws Exception {        
        InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"));
        jsonReader.setLenient(true);
        Object object = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, tClass);
        jsonReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        return tClass.cast(object);
```

}

Call this:

```
readGsonObject(httpResponse.getEntity(), Integer.class);
```